# Ranorex System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, ranorex

After I use my code when Ranorex is installed is works fine, but after  uninstalled it, I have a library of Ranorex payed version, but I don't install it on my PC, just I need the library. there an exception showed with this line of code

```
Form form = Host.Local.FindSingle<Ranorex.Form>("form[@processname='" + pr.ProcessName + "']");
```

On debug Mode shows ;

> 'Host.Local' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'

Exception :

> Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Ranorex.Core.dll
>   Additional information: The type initializer for
>   'Ranorex.Core.ElementEngine' threw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ranorex and it's components to work atleast Ranorex Runtime Licencse is required.

Comment: and where I put the license with VS2015? in debug file? or with project?